# Swapping 2 integers in assembly x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, swap

I have an integer pointer pointing to the start of an array of ints and I'm trying to swap two values in assembly x86. This is the code I have:

```
movq (%rdi,%rcx,4),%r8     # SWAP
movq 4(%rdi,%rcx,4),%r9   
movq %r9,(%rdi,%rcx,4)
movq %r8,4(%rdi,%rcx,4)
```

`rdi` contains the pointer and the address calculations for the two values are correct (`rcx` is just 0 in the first iteration), however, this is what happens when I do the swap:

```
(gdb) x/5wd $rdi
0x602010:    31    1    2    3
0x602020:    0
(gdb) x/5wd $rdi
0x602010:    1     2    2    3
0x602020:    0
(gdb) x/5wd $rdi
0x602010:    1     31    2    3
0x602020:    0
```

As you can see the 3rd value is replaced by the swap of the first and second values and I can't understand why. Any suggestions about where I should be looking for my mistake?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please avoid showing code in images

Comment: Please consider posting the gdb output as text instead of an image.  Posting text as images is highly frowned upon on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`movq` moves 8 bytes, while you expect it to move 4.
Use `movl` instead, with `r8d` and `r9d` (the low 32 bits of r8 and r9).

Or the other way around, offset your memory accesses 8 bytes from one another instead of 4 to swap qwords.

Comment: Or swap a pair of dwords in memory with a qword rotate, like `rorq $32, (%rdi,%rcx,4)`, but that may introduce store-forwarding stalls.